# Movie database API with similar movies

Tags: .net, api, imdb

Need api to get movie recommendations like imdb does. themoviedb is not providing corresponding IMDB id when searching for similar movies(by the way their similar movies list is really strange). Rotten tomatoes API has just 10000 requests per day and http://www.omdbapi.com/ is not providing similar movies. So im stuck here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried Rotten Tomatoes API?

Comment: Yes, already solved that issue. Im using Rotten Tomatoes API's alias(to get rotten tomatoes ID by IMDB id) and then take their similar movies(method returns really nice results!) They allow just 10000 request per day, so when i do my 2 request - i cache the result in local DB for 20 days to reduce requests to rotten tomatoes. So that was my solution.

Comment: i do the same thing.. if you are working on some similar project, lets share some ideas and thoughts... i m working for myself.